# Amid/Amidst as In the middle of

Tags: word-usage

I often use the words *amid/amidst* instead of *among/amongst* and instead of *between* or *surrounded by*, but I could never understand it's meaning *"in the middle of"* as [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amid) and [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/amid) tell us that it has this meaning.

Examples that they provide still carry the meanings of *"among/surrounded by"*.

- Our dream home, set *amid* magnificent rolling countryside.
- On the floor, *amid* mounds of books, were two small envelopes.

I also know that *amid/amidst* have meanings *"during/with the accompaniment of/In an atmosphere or against a background of/through"* but I almost never hear this word used with those meaning.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: What is the strange meaning "in the middle of" that Amid and Amidst have?

Comment: "in the middle of" is essentially a synonym of "surrounded by". In your two example sentences, "amid" is interchangeable with "among" (both sentences) or "surrounded by" (actually "surrounded by" would replace the verb phrase "set amid" in sentence 1) or "in the middle of" (both sentences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(mostly copied from my comment below the question)

"in the middle of" in this sense is essentially a synonym of "surrounded by". In your two example sentences, "amid" is interchangeable with "among" (both sentences) or "surrounded by" (actually "surrounded by" would replace the verb phrase "set amid" in sentence 1) or "in the middle of" (both sentences).

An alternative form of "in the middle of" is "[in the midst of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+midst+of)". The link also gives a couple of other instances where you can use the idiom.